# Change http to https in Google analytcs

Tags: google-search-console

In my Google Analytics - Property - All Products - Search Console - Adjust Link I see http link to my site. I want to change it to https.

Can't find a way to add another link or change existing

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not the google analytics helpdesk.

Answer (score 0):

You can't update the protocol. You have to make a new https: search console property (keep the old one for historical) and update the link in GA.